# In the following program, I don't understand the answer A::h() and A::h()

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, virtual-functions

In my opinion, pA is a pointer of type A but holding the address of b_object which is of type B. Since h() is a virtual function in class B (inherited from A) and also overloaded, so it will hide the function h() of the base class A, therefore, I expected the answer to be B::h(), but answer is A::h(), I don't know why and how.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
   public:
      virtual void f(int){cout << "A::f(int)" << endl;}
      virtual void g(double){cout << "A::g(double)" << endl;}
      int h(A*){cout << "A::h()" << endl; }
};

class B: public A
{
    public:
        void f(int){cout << "B::f(int)" << endl;}
        virtual int h(B*){cout << "B::h()" << endl;}
};

class C : public B
{
      void g(double){cout << "C::g(double)" << endl;}
      int h(B*){cout << "C::h()" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    A a_object;
    B b_object;
    C c_object;
    A*pA;
    pA = &b_object;
    pA->h(&a_object);
    pA->h(&b_object);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

Comment: `h` is not virtual in `A`.

Comment: When you have `A*`, compiler will look *only* into `A` for function declarations. If the function in `A` is `virtual`, it will look up the vtable to find correct function, otherwise it will simply take the definition from `A` and call it. Hiding has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 3):

Within the class `A` the function `h` is not a virtual function

```
int h(A*){cout << "A::h()" << endl; }
```

In the both calls of the function `h`

```
pA->h(&a_object);
pA->h(&b_object);
```

the function `h` is searched in the class `A` due to the type of the pointer `pA`.

```
A*pA;
```

As the function `h` is not a virtual function then it is unimportant that the pointer `pA` is assigned by the address of an object of the derived class `B`.

```
   pA = &b_object;
```

and that the function accepts as an argument a pointer to an object of the derived class `B`

```
pA->h(&b_object);
```

because a pointer to a derived class can be implicitly converted to a pointer to its base class.